# IR receiver somewhow being triggered by cell phone screen?

Tags: flipflop, 555, infrared, interference

First time asking a question here.

I am curious why the TSOP4838 ir sensor is acting erratically when my Google Pixel 2's screen is facing it.

As you can see from the schematic, I have a 555 arranged as a Schmitt trigger, with the output going to the CLK of a 4013 configured as a latch, which ultimately activates the NPN relay driver. The circuit works as expected when facing a 38 kHz IR LED at the sensor, but also falsely triggers when facing my cell phone's screen towards the sensor.

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Does your phone have an infrared based proximity sensor?

Comment: You have no frequency discrimination - so it's working correctly.

Comment: @KevinWhite Thank you for answering so swiftly. So despite the fact that the sensor is tuned to only detect signals at 38k, there is additional frequency discrimination I should use? What kind of design would this entail?

Comment: The Pixel 2 had face unlock, I wonder if it still emits IR?  Use another camera that can detect IR and look at your Pixels front side to see if it is emitting IR.

Comment: @Craftyjam - Sorry, I was wrong. I misinterpreted your schematic. The symbol you are using is for a plain phototransistor as opposed to a module. The TSOP4838 should filter the signal acceptably. It is possible that the proximity sensor near the ear section of the phone is triggering it. I worked on the design of the iPhone proximity sensor and we used about 100kHz, not 38kHz but the Pixel2 may use a frequency close to 38kHz.

Comment: do you have an IR filter installed?

Comment: @Craftyjam - By putting your finger over various parts of the phone screen (and bezel) you should be able to determine where the interference is coming from.

Comment: @KevinWhite After covering the ear section of phone, the interference disapeared. Is there any way i can insulate the sensor from picking up this type of interference? Maybe using a mirror to reflect the light onto the sensor rather than having it directly exposed to cell phone ir emissions?

Comment: How much heat is your screen producing?